# providing SSL for Web Service that runs on IIS

Tags: iis, ssl

I need to provide SSL to my Web Service that runs on IIS (ASMX web service). 
As I understand there are 3 ways to do that:
1) create my own certificate using IIS
2) buy it
3) get some open source certificate

For instance my Web Service has constant IP and communicates with only one web site on client side (client is in PHP).
Can someone give an advice, what is the best way for me to provide it and what are advantages and disadvantages of 3 ways to do that, or just point to some article for complete beginners in SSL issue.

Thanx for assistance!

Comment: There is no such thing as an "open source" certificate. There might be some free CAs, but they tend not to be recognised in most systems/browsers (in which case you might as well create your own CA or use self-signed certificates).

Comment: yeah. when I say "open source" SSL I mean something like this: https://www.startssl.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating your own cert is useful only if your end users are either completely uncaring about security or they have some other way of verifying the validity of your server - generally an internal network or something similar.

The free cert issuers tend to be unrecognized. This has the same effect as self-signing.... i.e. pointless since the end user will get the same warning messages.

There are very inexpensive options though. I've used GoDaddy before @ USD $13 a year.

Here's a link to all the trusted certificate authorities that Mozilla adds to FireFox:
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/certs/included/

IE and Chrome have similar lists.

Comment: and what about the difference between inexpensive options (like GoDaddy) and more expensive?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I've used the big boys at work before (like VeriSign) but they don't seem to offer anything that the cheap ones don't have also.